# External FDQN on Oracle Cloud

Tags: networking, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I wonder if there is a way to access a compute instance on OCI via FDQN externally? I have a VPC with a subnet, connected to a IG. So I can access via it's public IP no problem, but FQDN doesn't resolve properly from the outside world. It seems to be resolving ok within the network though. Is this "by-design", or I am missing some config?

Thank you!

Comment: It's by design. The FQDN resolves to the instance's private IP address. See some more info [here](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/dns.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Oracle doesn't publish their server for DNS resolution. External query yields no results:

```
C:\dig oraclevcn.com

; <<>> DiG 9.12.2-P2 <<>> oraclevcn.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Internally it resolves just fine:

```
$ dig +short any ns oraclevcn.com
;; Warning, extra type option
vcn-dns.oraclevcn.com.
```

Koodos to Oracle! So no way to access an instance externally via the provided FQDN.